# Restoring SQL Server DB, replacing the existing one

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to restore SQL server DB, replacing the existing one but donot know how to do it.
My purpose is to restore the backup file selected by user, no matter if file with this name is already attached to the server or not.  If it is there, it should be replaced by the new one.

Could any body give me vb.net code for it?

Thanks

Comment: People normally do not respond well to `Plz give me teh codez` questions.

Comment: I'm interested to know this too. Interesting question.

Comment: http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=40

Comment: well JNK, my experience is entirely opposite.  There are more good people on the planet than ...... ones !

Comment: Because people help you when you are lazy doesn't mean that they are "good".  There's nothing wrong with asking for help, but saying "Here is my issue please give me the code for it" is **lazy**.  It shows you have not put forth any effort at all into solving your problem, but expect others to solve it for you.  Some that's asked almost 300 questions would hopefully know where to start by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy and hard.

Have you worked out what the sql is?

Are you restoring the entire back up or just a number of dbs out of it.

Do you want to sanity check it at all?

How are you going to deal with sql server's service account not having permission to see the file?

What about those using the database when it's requested.

Do you want to show progress as it restores?

Are there other considerations, emailing, permissions, MSMQ, replication....
Which sql server versions are you coping with?

If you aren't going to do this properly don't bother,m leave it the their IT / DBA people. The more hand holding you want to do, the more the scope will creep...